# DataFrame.resample() closed not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas

First, let's create one sample per minute of data:

```
>>> index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=60*24*400, freq='T')
>>> series = pd.Series(range(60*24*400), index=index)
>>> series.head()
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
2000-01-01 00:04:00    4
```

I can see the impact of `closed` when resampling to daily frequency:

```
>>> series.resample('D', closed="right").head()
1999-12-31       0.0  # <-- here, I get some data labeled 1999
2000-01-01     720.5
2000-01-02    2160.5
2000-01-03    3600.5
2000-01-04    5040.5
Freq: D, dtype: float64
>>> series.resample('D', closed="left").head()
2000-01-01     719.5
2000-01-02    2159.5
2000-01-03    3599.5
2000-01-04    5039.5
2000-01-05    6479.5
```

This is the behaviour I expect from [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> closed : {‘right’, ‘left’}
>
> Which side of bin interval is closed.

Now, if I resample to a monthly frequency:

```
>>> series.resample('M', closed="right").head()
2000-01-31     22319.5  # <-- ?
2000-02-29     65519.5
2000-03-31    108719.5
2000-04-30    152639.5
2000-05-31    196559.5
Freq: M, dtype: float64
>>> series.resample('M', closed="left").head()
2000-01-31     21599.5
2000-02-29     64079.5
2000-03-31    107279.5
2000-04-30    151199.5
2000-05-31    195119.5
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

How come I don't get a `1999-12-31` sample when using `closed="right"`?

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.22.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be due to the label property. Documentation you have linked described it as

> label : {‘right’, ‘left’}
>   Which bin edge label to label bucket with. The default is ‘left’ for all frequency offsets except for ‘M’, ‘A’, ‘Q’, ‘BM’, ‘BA’, ‘BQ’, and ‘W’ which all have a default of ‘right’.

Try doing:

```
series.resample('D', closed="right", label="right").head()
```

You see a different behaviour for Month and Day because the default label is "left" for D and "right for M.

Comment: Oh, right. I guess you meant `series.resample('M', closed="right", label="left").head()`. But yes, you're right.